# Center a Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

Using the following CSS, I'm trying to make a navigation bar at the top of the page (fixed to the top) but instead of it being on the absolute left of the screen, I want it centered.

```
ul#list-nav
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:28px;
    font-size:120%;
    display:inline;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    border:none;
    z-index:1000;
}

ul#list-nav li
{
    float:left;
}
ul#list-nav a
{
    background-color:#1F1F1F;
    color:#C4C4C4;
    /*display:block;*/
    padding:5px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
}

ul#list-nav a:hover
{
    background-color:#4D4D4D;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul#list-nav a:active
{
    background-color:#9C9C9C;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Attempts so far make it a vertical list, or make the buttons start in the center (rather than be centered). How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: below is the HTML ... this list is the only thing being styled.

```
<ul id="list-nav">
            <li><a href="/ourbs/index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ourbs/categories/projects.php">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ourbs/categories/opinion.php">Opinion</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ourbs/categories/humour.php">Humour</a></li>      
            <li><a href="/ourbs/categories/games.php">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ourbs/categories/movies.php">Movies</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ourbs/categories/tvshows.php">TV Shows</a></li>
</ul>
```

EDIT2: here's a jsFiddle if this helps
http://jsfiddle.net/752jU/1/

Comment: The answers you've received so far are only guesses without seeing your HTML.  Also posting a jsFiddle would be great.

Comment: I've added the HTML but I will look into jsFiddle right now, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering the Navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218808/centering-the-navigation-bar) and a host of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one wrapper `div` to accomplish this...

http://jsfiddle.net/752jU/5/

*Note:  By using `display: inline` my answer is also [good in IE 6 & 7](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html), if that matters.*

**CSS:**

```
div#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height:28px;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    border: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
ul#list-nav {
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
ul#list-nav li {
    display: inline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="list-nav">
        <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ourbs/categories/projects.php">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="/categories/opinion.php">Opinion</a></li>
        <li><a href="/categories/humour.php">Humour</a></li>        
        <li><a href="/categories/games.php">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="/categories/movies.php">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/categories/tvshows.php">TV Shows</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert the list in 3 nested divs:

In your css:

```
div#container1
{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%
}

div#container2
{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align: center;
}

div#container3
{  
  display:inline-block; 
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<div id="container1">
<div id="container2">
<div id="container3">
<ul id="list-nav">
...
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jZQ4v/ for a version of your code that center properly

Comment: That's generally good advice.  However, you have not yet seen the OP's HTML so I don't know how you could give any answer.

Comment: @rar, I don't know how you expect anyone to figure this out without seeing your HTML.

Comment: you can't just copy-paste your previous  list in the '...'. for example you may want to remove the "position:fixed" from the list style

Comment: I've added the HTML, I figured since it was only the list that's being styled that it wouldn't make much of a difference with or without the HTML, but I've included it in the original post.

Comment: It still refuses to move to the center. Your answer works in your fiddle, but doesn't when I try to add it to mine.

Comment: i've forked your fiddle, updating the answer

Comment: Regarding the method used in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh4Jr/)... you will have to carefully tweak the width and make sure it renders the same cross-browser.  I'm in Safari and the last menu item is wrapping to a new line.

Comment: @sparky, i was not able to make it work without a fixed size... do you know how?

Comment: The problems:  When you use inline methods, you can't use left/right margins to center it.  When you use block methods, the elements expand to full container width by default.  Let me try to find something.

Comment: The problems you explain are the ones I've run into. inline display for some reason stops me wrong adjusting where it is positioned, and block containers kill other things I'm trying to do. So it's like there's no way to center what I'm trying to make here. That's why I posted here.

Comment: i've removed the fixed-width requirement, and updated my answer

Comment: @sparky, can you test it in safari?

Comment: I'm running into problems with exterior CSS so I will fix that at this point. Thank you.

Comment: I got it and posted answer.  Three wrappers are overkill and not required.

Comment: @rar: It should also be noted that `display: inline-block` is [no good below IE 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

Comment: @Sparky, i redirect readers to the answer of Danny but your is good also (IE6 i hate you)

Comment: I've changed my answer selection to Danny's for future readers, but I appreciate all of the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#list-nav {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 120%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    border: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#list-nav li {    
    display: inline;    
    text-align: center;
}
#list-nav a {   
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;   
    display: inline;   
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px;    
    font-size: 14px;
}
#list-nav a:hover {  
    background-color: #4D4D4D;   
    text-decoration: none;
}
#list-nav a:active {   
    background-color: #9C9C9C;  
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I removed all unnecessary coding which didn't alter the menu in any way.

See a live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/YFDeX/1/

**Edit:** Altered for compatibility with IE6+

Hope this helps.

Comment: It should be noted that `display: inline-block` is [no good below IE 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

Comment: @Sparky672 Consider it fixed, and compatible IE6+ and all other browsers without the need of an extra element.

Comment: You did not have to fix it... it's just good to make note of compatibility issues for the reader.

Comment: @Sparky672 I generally like to make things compatible with as many browsers as I can, I just hadn't realised inline-block wasn't supported by IE 6&7, thank you for pointing it out to me.

Comment: The only issue with this answer is that it removes the "fixed" property which made my navigation bar remain at the top as you scrolled down the page. It's the only minor issue, and I can live with that not being present if it's centered. I did try to add position:fixed; but it messes with other properties it seems.

Comment: @rar see the second revision of my fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/YFDeX/2/ i've put the menu in div which wraps it and keeps your position: fixed; value, i've fixed it to 0px for the top, left and right values, change it as you require.

Comment: @rar, And with Danny's last jsFiddle, this answer has fully evolved into what I had worked out first (_fixed position wrapper and display inline_). lol.